# Apply pickadate jquery plugin to a dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating an input field and trying to apply the [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) jquery plugin to it but it's not working.

I have a button that triggers an event when the user clicks on it and then a new field is generated bellow and so on.

I have the following code to dynamically create the input fields.

```
var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text"><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a><div id="align_new"><ul><li><span>Start : </span><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="list'+FieldCount+'_start_date"></li><li><span>End : </span><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="list'+FieldCount+'_end_date"></li></ul></div></div>');
            x++;
        }

return false;
});
```

Each field has a different id: starting from `list2_start_date` and `list2_end_date` and the number increases each time the user add another field.

On my static input field the plugin works just fine but it doesn't apply the plugin to the dynamically created fields.

The functions I have to deal with the events are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#list1_start_date' ).pickadate()
    $( '#list1_end_date' ).pickadate()

    $( '#list2_start_date' ).pickadate()
    $( '#list2_end_date' ).pickadate()

    $( '#list3_start_date' ).pickadate()
    $( '#list3_end_date' ).pickadate()

    $( '#list4_start_date' ).pickadate()
    $( '#list4_end_date' ).pickadate()

    $( '#list5_start_date' ).pickadate()
    $( '#list5_end_date' ).pickadate()

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="InputsWrapper">
        <span class="new_span">Field :</span>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="new_span" style="width:186px;"></span>
        <div id="align_new">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Start :</span>
                    <input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="datepicker" id="list1_start_date">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>End :</span>
                    <input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="datepicker" id="list1_end_date">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, I came up with the solution just adding .find() after the .append()

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Just add .find() after the append:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<code_here>').find('.datepicker').pickadate();
```

The code gets:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text"><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a><div id="align_new"><ul><li><span>Start : </span><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="list'+FieldCount+'_start_date"></li><li><span>End : </span><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="list'+FieldCount+'_end_date"></li></ul></div></div>').find('.datepicker').pickadate();
```